# BlackBerry AutoCompleteField - how to accept only a part of existing string

Tags: blackberry, autocomplete

The AutoCompleteField suggests a list of strings to choose from but I cannot find a way to enter only a part of existing string.
For example: In AutoCompleteFieldDemo sample we have a 'month' field. When we enter 'ju' in that field we have a list of available strings 'June' and 'July'. When you press 'Enter' - a whole 'June' or 'July' is selected and accepted. When you press 'Back' button - the field is cleared completely.
The question is how to accept 'ju' as a final string for that field and move on to the next control? Is it something the standard control is not capable of?

P.S. Actually the question is a duplicate of my topic [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/AutoCompleteField-accept-a-part-of-a-string/td-p/1448717).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution, after trying for a couple of hours... and looking up in forums with no success i came up with this solution:

```
final AutoCompleteField autofield = new AutoCompleteField(list){
            public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context){
                super.fieldChanged(field, context);
                if (flag){
                    list.clear();
                    String strings_input[] = new String[1];
                    strings[0] = getEditField().getText();
                    list.addDataSet(0, strings_input, "blah blah",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
                    list.addDataSet(1, strings_months, "blah blah 2",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);   
                }
            }

            public void onSelect(Object selection, int type){
                 flag = false;
                 super.onSelect(selection, type);
                 getEditField().setText(((BasicFilteredListResult)selection)._object.toString());
                 flag = true;
             }
        };
```

This actually inserts into the filtered list the text you are typing so you can select it from the drop down.

Hope it helps